# R Efficient recursive calculations for a large dataset

Tags: r

I would like to take a single column of numeric data, in this case bound between 0 and 10 and subtract a fixed value on an iterative basis. In my current paradigm, each column represents a time step and is dependent on the previous timestep (t-1). This dependency is important because I would like to define columns in which the number resets to 10 and then begins to degrade once again. My main issue is that this is very inefficient for a large dataset and I am fairly certain that there is a quicker and more scalable way to accomplish this task.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(data=0,nrow=10,ncol=10))
df[,1] <- data.frame(runif(10,0,10))
df[c(3,5,7),4] <- 10
degradation <- .16
for (year in 2:10){
 df[,year][df[,year]!=10] <- df[,year-1][df[,year]!=10]-degradation
}
df[df<0]<-0
```

Here is a very simple and inefficient example of how I would like the data to look. Its possible I am stuck in my old excel way of thinking, so I am open to different ways of structuring the data if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data's a matrix, so don't use a data frame

```
m <- matrix(data=0, nrow=10, ncol=10)
m[,1] <- runif(10, 0, 10)
m[c(3,5,7), 4] <- 10
```

Avoid replicating computations by using a variable (`ridx`) to represent the intermediate value; use two-dimensional subset-assignment

```
degradation <- .16
for (year in 2:10) {
    ridx <- m[, year] != 10
    m[ridx, year] <- m[ridx, year-1L] - degradation
}
```

If the idea is that there is a constant reset rate *r*, then after some period of time any individual row has probability *p0* = *r* of having just been reset, *p1* = (1 - *r*) *r* being reset 1 time period ago, *p2* = (1 - *r*)^2 *r* reset 2 time periods ago, ..., *pt* =  (1 - *r*)^*t* *r* reset *t* time periods ago (this describes a geometric distribution). Corresponding values are *x0* = 10, *x1* = 10 - *d*, *x2* = 10 - 2 *d*, ..., *xt* = 10 - *t d*. After *t* = 10 / *d* time periods, if there's been no reset then the value is 0. So for instance the probability that the sample is non-zero is sum_{i = 0}^{i = 10 / d - 1} pi and the average value of non-zero rows is sum_{i = 0}^{i = 10 / d - 1} pi xi. These (and the probability of individual states from 10 ... 0) are easily calculated without simulation.

Comment: @gvanderbilt added a little on a more mathematical analysis.